# Running tests in parallel with Karate junit5 1.3.1

Tags: java, testing, karate, junit5

I am using `Runner.path("").parallel(20);` to execute the tests, but looks like the execution is not parallel after-all based on the time consumed and I think the Karate HTML report Summary also tells the same story.

[image]

As you can see, one scenario finishes and only then, in the timeline, another scenario starts to be executed.
Any suggestions for this please?

Comment: you can't use the JUnit support for parallel execution, refer linked answer. if you still have problems, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue